# FIbroblast vs fibrocyte

Tags: nomenclature, histology

After i had been studing for histology examp i tried to solved one nominclature dilema.Its about fibrocytes and fibroblast.

In my histology book is statment, that fibrocytes is special type of cell which can be differentiated to different cell types by specific occasion ( for example exposure to transcript factors).

Then fibroblast is cell of connective tissue. Its differentiated.

Why is differentiated cell named with blast (usually active type) istead fibrocyte (usually the differentiated one)?

Comment: If i  misunderstand something i ll be grafull for correction.

Comment: See the second part of the answer marked as duplicate: *Blast cells may also be cells that produce materials* applies to fibroblasts. There isn't anything particularly unique about this example, you've just focused on one but not both of the meanings of the -blast suffix.